# How to control where script run by cron saves files?

Tags: cron, perl

I've got the following cron job that runs at 6 am every morning:

```
00 6 * * * /Users/username/path/to/script/wget.pl 1;
```

The script, written in perl, fetches the latest files from a website.

Within the perl script, the path gets changed with:

```
`cd '/path/to/directory'`
```

However, all the files downloaded aren't getting saved to `/path/to/directory` they get saved in `/Users/username`.

What can I do to get the script to save it in the directory I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `cd /path` within your script only changes the directory for the shell that is spawned to execute the shell command.  It's the same thing as doing

```
system('cd /path');
```

It doesn't change the cwd (current working directory) of the script itself.  The best way to do it is to have your script write the files to a specific directory.  If your perl script is a straight wrapper for wget, you can do away with the perl script and do something along the lines of:

```
wget -O /full/path/to/file http://host/url/here
```

If you want to do this within perl (example idea, not tested)...

```
use LWP::Simple qw(get);
my $url = 'http://host/url/here';
my $result = get $url;
open(my $fh, ">", "/path/to/file");
print $fh $result;
close($fh)
```

One final option (again not tested)...

```
00 6 * * * cd /path/you/want;/Users/username/path/to/script/wget.pl 1;
```

Comment: Ok, I ended up using the --directory-prefix option for wget to get this to work.